# Multiseat with Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 graphics card in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: radeon, amd-graphics, multiseat

Trying to create a multiseat as per [the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiseatTeam/Instructions) with

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM]
```

card which has hdmi, vga and dvi outputs in the same card. Already working with single head with fglrx driver, but I could not figure out how to create a 99-multiseat.conf as described [here in the aforementioned doc](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiseatTeam/Instructions#Example_.232) for ATI radeon cards with fglrx drivers. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Tried multiple ways to make each head (DVI, VGA and HDMI) of the card, but without success. So I added a new NVIDIA FX5200 dualhead VGA card and it works with separate graphic cards, but tearing down the graphics card into two consoles which used to be possible earlier according to [this article](http://netpatia.blogspot.se/2009/07/multiseat-with-nvidia-card.html) and [this one](http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/~jori/page/index.php?n=Misc.DualSeatX)?! hmmm ...